# TypeError: client.commands.filtrer is not a function

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hello I have a problem with my discord help command. When I start the bot and I send the command, the bot crash with this error : **TypeError: client.commands.filtrer is not a function**

Can u help me please Cuz idk how to do something else.

The code:

```
        let infoembed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('AQUA')
        .setTitle('Info Commands')
        .setDescription(`>>>> ${client.commands
            .filtrer((cmd) => cmd.category === 'Info')
            .map((cmd) => `\'${cmd.name}\'`)
            .join(', ')}`)


        let ModerationEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('AQUA')
        .setTitle('Moderation Commands')
        .setDescription(`>>>> ${client.commands
            .filtrer((cmd) => cmd.category === 'Moderation')
            .map((cmd) => `\'${cmd.name}\'`)
            .join(', ')}`)


        let OtherEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('AQUA')
        .setTitle('Other Commands')
        .setDescription(`>>>> ${client.commands
            .filtrer((cmd) => cmd.category === 'Other')
            .map((cmd) => `\'${cmd.name}\'`)
            .join(', ')}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `client.commands` you defined is an discord.js Collection. It doesn't have any method called `filtrer`. I think you are trying to **filter** the collection. So replace `filtrer` with `filter`.